# Find on models with HasAndBelongsToMany relationship returns unexpected format in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I'm working on tagging system in cakephp.  Tags can be children of other tags that are roots.  (No children of children).

The models are User and Tag.  Their relationships look like this:

```
//User.php:

public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Tag' => array(
            'className' => 'Tag',
            'joinTable' => 'users_tags',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'unique' => true,
        ),
    );

//Tag.php:
var $belongsTo = array(
        'Parent' => array(
            'className' => 'Tag',
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
            'dependent' => true,
        ),
    );
```

When I try to do a simple paginate, like so,

```
$this->User->recursive = 2;
$this->set('users', $this->paginate());
```

I get some weird results that look like this:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'User' => array(
        ...
    ),
    'Tag' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'parent_id' => null,
            ...
            'Parent' => array()
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'parent_id' => '1',
            ...
            'Parent' => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'parent_id' => null,
                ...
            )
        )
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'User' => array(
        ...
    ),
    'Tag' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'parent_id' => null,
            ...
            'Parent' => array(
                'Parent' => array()  //What's up with this parent inside the parent?
            )
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'parent_id' => '1',
            ...
            'Parent' => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'parent_id' => null,
                ...
            )
        )
    )
)
```

)

You'll notice that the tag that returned weird results is actually the same tag (id #1) as the first tag in the array.  I'm confused as to why it would be right before, and wrong the second time..?

Comment: That is due to recursive is set to `2`. Hide that code line and check what it outputs.

Comment: I would advise to stop using recursive, set it to -1 in the AppModel and use the containable behavior on all Models.

Comment: I did try removing recursive, but then I don't get the parents, which I do need for what I'm doing with the data.  And again, the first and the third tag are actually the same tag, (owned by two different users) so I still don't feel like it explains why one of them is weird and one of them isn't.  I'll try using containable though.

Comment: I just tried replacing the recursive line with recursive = -1, and then setting $this->paginate = array('contain' => array('Tag' => array('Parent'))), and it returns the exact same results.